# How to use NGramTokenizerFactory or NGramFilterFactory?

Tags: solr, tokenize, lucene

Recently, I am studying how to store and index using Solr. I want to do facet.prefix search. With whitespace tokenizer, "Where are you" will be splited into three words and indexed. If I search facet.prefix="where are", no result will be returned.

I google and found NGramFilterFactory can help me. But when I apply this filter factory, I found the result is "w, h, e, ..., wh, ..", which split the sentence by character, not by token word.

I use the parameters maxGramSize and minGramSize, set to 1 and 3. Does the NGramFilterFactory work right? Should I add some other parameters? Is there some other filter factories which can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how ngram works. In what context are you using facet.prefix?

Comment: Not quite an answer for you, but a clarification. NGram works on individual characters. It can take the word "cat" and slice it into tokens like "c","a","t","ca","at", and "cat". It *looks* like you may be wanting what is called a shingle tokenizer, which works much the same, but at a word level instead of a character level.

Comment: Hi Mauricio, I want to use facet.prefix for autocompletion. With default method, the three words will be indexed separately. When doing facet.prefix search, of course, searching "w" will return "where", but searching "where ", nothing will be returned. So I want to add the tokens for indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facets should only be applied to non tokenized fields like strings. if you want that results will be displayed for "what are" use no tokenizer at all for that field (or a copyField directive). I guess that you want to use facet.prefix for autocompletion. you can do this, [look here](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/use-cases-of-faceted-search-for-apache-solr/).

for the ngramtokenizer [check this out](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/09/08/auto-suggest-from-popular-queries-using-edgengrams/).